# Numerical evaluation of the period of a limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

How can I calculate all the periods of the limit cycle of the Ueda-Duffing equation with forcing:

$\ddot{x} + k \dot{x} + x^3 = B \cos(t) $

for each set of parameters $(k, B)$ ?

Edit:

The equation exhibits sub-harmonic resonance for some sets of parameters (and chaotic behaviour too). 
E.g. for $k=0.08, B=0.2$ there are 5 coexisting attractors  of period $2n\pi  $ with $n=1, 2, 3$

Comment: I numerically evaluated solution after n cycles (in order to allow for convergence) and then evaluated delta = abs(x(n) - x(n + k)). The lowest k for which delta < epsilon (e.g. epsilon = 0.001) is the period.

Comment: You might consider using a differential equation solver with event detection capability for finding periods.

Comment: does such differential equation solver exist?

Comment: Is this a trick question? The limit cycle has to be in resonance with the forcing, is driven by it, which means that the period is $2\pi$.

Comment: @LutzL this is not generally true: there are some areas in the (k,B)  space where there is sub-harmonic resonance (e.g. period of the limit cycle is two or three times the period of the forcing). This is exactly what I am investigating.

Comment: Then please add an expanded version of your previous comment to the problem description in the question text. Indeed for large $B$ and very small $k$ (e.g., $k=0.001$, $B=5$) the resulting behavior is rather chaotic.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some exploratory python script that uses at its core a boundary value solver to find the closed loops from a systematic sweep of the relevant part of the phase space:

```
k=0.08; B=0.2
def odesys(u,t): return [u[1], B*np.cos(t)-k*u[1]-u[0]**3 ]
def bc(ya, yb): return yb-ya 

def norm(a): return max(abs(a))

rows, cols = 2, 3
points = [np.array([10.0,10.0])]; # have some non-relevant point 
for p in range(rows*cols): # loop over periods T=(p+1)*2*pi
    plt.subplot(rows,cols,p+1);
    n=p+1;
    t_init = np.linspace(0, 2*n*np.pi, n*10+1)
    t_sol  = np.linspace(0, 2*n*np.pi, n*500+1)
    for x in np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,5+1):
      for v in np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,4+1):
        u0 = np.array([ x, v ]);
        u_init = odeint(odesys, u0, t_init); 
        res = solve_bvp(lambda t,u:odesys(u,t), bc, t_init, u_init.T, tol=5e-3, max_nodes=n*500+1)
        print res.message,"\n",n,": ",res.sol(0)
        if res.success and min( norm(pp - res.sol(0)) for pp in points ) > 5e-3:
            res = solve_bvp(lambda t,u:odesys(u,t), bc, res.x, res.y, tol=1e-5, max_nodes=n*10000+1)
            print res.message, "\n refine to",res.sol(0) 
            if res.success and min( norm(pp - res.sol(0)) for pp in points ) > 1e-4:
                for j in range(n): points.append(res.sol(2*np.pi*j))
                u_sol = res.sol(t_sol);
                plt.plot(u_sol[0], u_sol[1], label="$u_0=$(%.6f,%.6f)"%(u_sol[0,0], u_sol[1,0])); 
    plt.grid(); plt.legend(), plt.title("T=%d$\cdot2\pi$"%n);
plt.show()
```

For the parameters posted in the question, $k=0.08$, $B=0.2$, screening up to period 12 (times $2\pi$) gave only periodic orbits for up to period 3.
[image]

Increasing the forcing and reducing the friction coefficient to  $k=0.02$, $B=1.5$ periodic orbits were found for periods $1,3,6$ with as expected a more chaotic behavior
[image]

Comment: Does this method could work for set of equations ?

Comment: @Dadep : That depends on what you understand under "set of equations". In principle, you can use a boundary solver in the same way to find limit cycles in higher dimensions. But you have to consider that the search space for initial conditions becomes much larger, and that the existence of limit cycles becomes a fragile property in dimensions bigger than 2.

Comment: @LutzL Why is it a fragile property?

Comment: Because it is more likely that you get a strange attractor or fill the space chaotically. The Poincaré-Bendixson theorem that guarantees limit cycles in 2D heavily relies on the existence of an "inside" of a closed curve and other geometric properties that are only true on a 2D plane.

Comment: @LutzL Okay, that depends on understanding of the word "fragile" then. To me "fragile" means that you can destroy something easily which is obviously not true for hyperbolic limit cycles. I won't bet what is more likely, chaos or regular dynamics, though. However, if you consider a family of systems, limit cycles and chaos go toe to toe. Many bifurcation scenarios that lead to complex dynamics involve limit cycles in some stages. Many chaotic attractors contain a lot of limit cycles in them. I wouldn't say that limit cycle is a rare guest in higher dimensions.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Could one say that to have a stable periodic orbit (which may be implied by the "limit" in "limit cycle") that persists also under perturbations of the system requires much more careful arguments and stronger assumptions.

Comment: @LutzL Well, yeah, kind of, probably :) I'll try to explain why I'm not betting on anything. There is an [anecdote](https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/21762/9789513936662.pdf) about Kolmogorov: when he was studying limit cycles on plane, he handed out his students problems with quadratic polynomial planar system and asked them, how many limit cycles there are. The surprising discovery was that among few hundred handouts none had a limit cycle, yet limit cycle (in theory) is as structurally stable and common as an equilibrium.