# Dynamical systems with large number of attractors and their dependence on the parameters?

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, intuition, visualization, motivation

It is much important to study the attractors in a dynamical system as these indicate how the system behaves once the initial transients are discarded.

Also, the study of systems with many numbers of attractors are interesting as the parameters are varied.

> I am looking for such examples of systems where there are many attractors in the dynamical systems and their dependence on the parameters.

Comment: If the attractor means the equilibrium point of the system. Then, consider the system: $\dot{x}_{1}=\omega x_{2}$, $\dot{x}_{2}=-\omega x_{1}$. The system is marginally stable, whose solution is periodic and a circle on the 2D plane. The radius of the circle is given by $\sqrt{x_{1}(0)^{2}+x_{2}(0)^{2}}$. The number of the attractors is infinite because it is a set.

Comment: Could the "Ueda-Duffing equation with forcing" like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679760/numerical-evaluation-of-the-period-of-a-limit-cycle) be an example for your question?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking how can it be an example? like i see that the period is increasing hinting to a chaotic behaviour but how many attractors are there?